# Intellij Code Symbol in Margin

Tags: intellij-idea

Can someone tell me what the rectangular symbol in the margin, right above the breakpoint, means?  I want to turn it off, but I am not sure what it is called.

This is Intellij 13.  Thanks.

[image: Intellij Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that this file's line has been modified locally.  It's being compared to your version control system.  In this case, it probably means you added a newline here.

There might be a better way than this to turn it off, but I haven't found it: Go to Settings -> Version Control.  From there click on the VCS tab and choose `<none>`.  This, of course, will remove all your VCS integration so it's pretty heavy handed.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]